# Zend Framework: get public path, get application url

Tags: zend-framework, url, public

Are there some proper Zend methods for:

a) receiving path to /public directory

b) receiving application url

Actually I'm using methods defined in Controller, but it feel right to use ready methods if they exits.

```
protected function _getApplicationUrl() {
    return $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
}

protected function _getPublicPath() {
    return realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/');
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding the application URL, `Zend_Controller_Request_Http` has a `getRequestUri()` method, but it deliberately (and somewhat frustratingly) excludes the scheme and hostname parts of the URL. In my apps I have resorted to grabbing `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` in the bootstrap and storing it in the registry so that I can use it later when constructing full URLs.

And from memory, no, there isn't any built-in method to get the location of the `public` folder, but the code you have is fine. Most apps I've seen `define()` all the paths in `index.php`, which I suppose is slightly safer (only because the path names get set sooner and become absolutely immutable) and ever so slightly faster, but lets not get into a debate about micro-optimizations! :-)

Answer (score 3):

1) If your virtual host point to ZF /public then in View you can get path by helper method `$this->baseUrl();` In controller `$this->view->baseUrl();` Otherwise create your own helper and use it.
2) In controller `$this->getRequest()->getHttpHost();`

Comment: What is the class to be included for using the `getHTTPPost()` ?

Comment: In controller : 
Call to undefined method Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request::getHttpHost()

Answer (score 1):

```
protected function _getPublicPath() {
    chdir(APPLICATION_PATH);
    return realpath("../public");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> a) receiving path to /public directory

Built-in php-function [getcwd()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) will give you the path to your site-host folder (ex. output "/home/my_cp/public_html/my_site.loc/www"). And then, you can construct whatever path you want.